# Why do I have to replug my headphones every time I restart/wake-up my computer?

Tags: windows-7, audio, troubleshooting, headphone-jack

I just recently bought a new computer ([CyberpowerPC Gamer Xtreme 1321](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16883229284)). If I plug-in my headphones or speakers a pop-up comes up asking if it's a microphone or headphones I'm plugging in. I always select headphones. The sound works fine then, but whenever my computer locks or goes to sleep or is restarted I always have to replug my headphones in for them to work.

Does anyone know anything about this?
I've tried this with both my headphones and my speakers and I get the same issue. I do NOT get this issue on my other computer.

Is this a hardware issue, a software issue, or a defect?

EDIT: My computer has both a microphone and headphone jack. no matter which one I plug it into I get the same pop-up and the same issues.

Comment: I can't find any details on the specifics of the sound card in that system, but it is quite likely a driver issue. As the device is emulating USB-style plug-and-play detection, chances are the device is not being woken up properly from the sleep state are restoring the previous configuration. More details on the audio hardware would be helpful.